# Needed step by step explaination of "while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF;"

Tags: c, stdin, getchar

I am aware that this question has been asked; but it hasn't been explained step by step and or thoroughly enough for me to understand how its executed; So, say that I have this part of code:

```
char ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Does the getchar() read a single character into the ch variable 1st and then make the comparison, that is, `ch != '\n' && ch != EOF`, leaving the newline escape sequence buffered, but not actually in the ch variable? And if so, doesn't this mean that it will just loop infinitely until it encounters the newline escape sequence/EOF? And if it encounters a newline escape sequence, is it stored in the ch variable? And if not, how not?

Comment: Start with the most-inner parens and work your way out. The assignment to `ch` from a stream-consuming `getchar()` call by-definition squashes the entire theory of *"leaving the newline escape sequence buffered, but not actually in the ch variable"*.

Comment: That code is broken. `getchar` returns `int` (not `char`) for a reason.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "newline escape sequence". An escape sequence like `\n` (backslash-n) is a feature of C source code; it's not a thing that exists in data at runtime.

Comment: "call by-definition squashes the entire theory of "leaving the newline escape sequence buffered, but not actually in the ch variable"". I don't know what this means. Can you elaborate? I'm sort of new to C.

Comment: "I don't understand what you mean when you say "newline escape sequence"." The "Enter key".

Comment: So ... the newline character? That's a character, not an escape sequence.

Answer (score 7):

```
char ch;
```

First we define a `ch` variable of type `char`.

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

This is a `while` loop. The loop condition is `(ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF` and the loop body is `;` (a null statement).

The loop condition consists of a `&&` (logical "and") and two operands, `(ch = getchar()) != '\n'` and `ch != EOF`. The `&&` operator always evaluates its left operand first.

`(ch = getchar()) != '\n'` is an inequality comparison. The right-hand side is `'\n'` (which represents a newline character). The left-hand side is an assignment expression, `ch = getchar()`.

`getchar()` calls the `getchar` function, which reads a character from `stdin` (standard input). If successful, this character is returned in the form of an `unsigned char` (usually in the range 0 .. 255); otherwise (if `getchar` fails) it returns `EOF` (which is an (implementation specific) negative value). This is why the return type of `getchar` is `int`: It needs to represent all valid character values *and* an error indicator.

This value is stored in `ch`. At this point, there are two possibilities:

1. `char` is an unsigned type in your implementation. In this case every successfully read character is stored as is, but `EOF` will be mapped to some normal character. If (as usual) `EOF` has the value `-1`, this will end up becoming `UCHAR_MAX` (typically 255).
2. `char` is a signed type in your implementation. In this case half of all possible character values are out of range (typically signed `char` has a range of -128 .. 127 and is unable to store values from 128 .. 255). Here things get a bit fuzzy: An out-of-range character will result either in an (implementation-defined) signal or will be converted to some other (implementation-defined) character. On the other hand, `EOF` will likely be preserved as is (unless it has a value less than `CHAR_MIN`, in which case you get an implementation-defined signal or conversion, as before).

An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after assignment. So `(ch = getchar())` returns the new value of `ch` (which is the input character mangled as described above). We compare this character to `'\n'` (newline). If it is a newline, `!=` yields false, `&&` yields false immediately, and the loop stops. (Note that depending on your implementation, other characters or even EOF might be misdetected as `'\n'` because of the mangling described above.)

If the input character is not a newline, `!=` yields true and `&&` proceeds to evaluate its right-hand operand. Here we compare `ch != EOF`. If we are in case #1 (i.e. `char` is an unsigned type), this comparison is always true because `EOF` is a negative value (unless we are in an even more exotic situation and `char`/`int` have the same size/range of possible values, which I'm not going to go into). If we are in case #2 (i.e. `char` is a signed type), this comparison is going to return false if `getchar` returned `EOF` (i.e. the end of the input was reached or an error occurred), and the loop stops. It's also going to misidentify certain characters (usually `UCHAR_MAX`, 255) as `EOF`.

Otherwise (i.e. if `ch` is not `'\n'` or `EOF`) the loop repeats and the next character is read and examined.

The intent of this code is to consume and discard input until a newline or end-of-input is reached.

But because of the way the code is written, it will in practice either not recognize `EOF` (and thus loop forever when reaching the end of the input) or treat valid input as `EOF` (and thus end early).

The fix is to declare `ch` as an `int`:

```
int ch;
```